# Ajax Jquery in Laravel not saving values to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a beginner in AJAX Jquery. My form will contain an array of values named *dualistbox_demo1[]* that the user has selected. However, it seems that the ajax function is not storing the values into my database.

My form in blade template:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'schools/assign',"id"=>"demoform"))}}
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1[]">

@foreach($user as $key => $value) 
  <option value="{{ $value->id}}">{{ $value->FirstName }} {{ $value->LastName }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

{{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-block')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is my js script:

```
<script>
$("#demoform").submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val(),
    success : function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My routes.php:

```
Route::post('/schools/assign', function(){
if(Request::ajax()){
    $AC = new AccessControlEntry();
    $AC->UserID     =   Input::get('duallistbox_demo1');
    $AC->save(); 
}
});
```

I really can't figure out what/where did I went wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `val` method on a String object. Missing `$`/`jQuery` in:

```
data: ('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val(),
```

Apart from that you should pass a `identifier:value` pair:

```
data: {
  'duallistbox_demo1': $('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val(),
}
```

Since `val` for a a multiple select returns an array you might want to call the `join` method for converting the array to a string.

Comment: I've just read on the join method, and found out that the implode function is an alias of join. 
So I've add on these codes to convert the array to string: 
`$selectedadmins = $('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val();
$stringadmins = implode(",", $selectedadmins);`

So inside my $.ajax function, 
`data: {
  'duallistbox_demo1': $('stringadmins'),
   },`

Storing into database still doesn't work. Did I do it wrongly? Really have hard time understanding Ajax jquery 
@undefined

Comment: @AnneTan `data: { 'duallistbox_demo1': $('stringadmins'), },` is not what I have suggested, you can't pass a jQuery object in that way, you should pass the value as a string, stringifing a jQuery object results in "can't convert a circular structure to JSON" error.